# Docker CPU Config

Tags: virtualization, docker, containers

I am running 6 containers on a server with 8 CPU each, assigned using run time option —cpuset-cpu
There are times when only a couple of containers have heavy processing to perform and others are sitting idle. Is it possible that at these times containers with Heavy load use CPU of idle containers as well ?

Similar to the concept of limit/reserve resources of VMware.

Answer (score 0):

The --cpuset-cpus option limits execution to those *specific* CPUs. It will not use other cores even if they are idle. Use this option only for workloads with extreme sensitivity to the latency of migration to another CPU.

What you actually want is the --cpus  option. Set it to some floating point number, like 6 for high priority containers or 2 for low priority ones. Adjust until host CPU is fully utilized.